# Use the value from a field in a table as a select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am trying to figure out how to use the values from a table as a select statement for example

table1 contains: 
column- cl1
Value - numb

table2:
column - numb
values 1,2,3,4

i want to select cl1 (value: numb) and then use it to run a statement

```
select numb from table2
```

so far i have used

```
select (select cl1 from table1) from table2;
```

this returns numb 4 times but i want the actual values

the output that i expect is 
1,2,3,4.

I want the query to select from table 1 which will return the field name and then use that field name(numb) as part of the select statement so expecting the end sql to look like:

```
select numb from table2;
```

However *numb* will be whatever is in table1;

Comment: You'll need to build the SQL as a string and they EXECUTE IMMEDIATE it

Comment: Honestly need more information here, can you add some dummy data and what data you are expecting out? Your question is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: i have added a bit more information hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You CAN do it, but you need to expand out your table to include by the list of possible columns that you are selecting with one row per column per source row. IF this is a large list of possibilities or a large data set....well, it ain't gonna be pretty.

For example:

```
With thedata as (
    select 1 row_id, 11 col1, 12 col2, 13 col3 from dual union all
    select 2 row_id, 21 col1, 22 col2, 23 col3 from dual union all
    select 3 row_id, 31 col1, 32 col2, 33 col3 from dual union all
    select 4 row_id, 41 col1, 42 col2, 43 col3 from dual )
, col_list as (
   select 1 col_id, 'col1' col from dual union all    
   select 2 col_id, 'col2' col from dual union all
   select 3 col_id, 'col3' col from dual )
select row_id, coldata
FROM  ( 
        -- here's where I have to mulitply the source data, generating one row for each possible column, and hard-coding that column to join to
        SELECT  row_id, 'col1' as col, col1 as coldata from thedata
        union all
        SELECT  row_id, 'col2' as col, col2 as coldata from thedata
        union all
        SELECT  row_id, 'col3' as col, col3 as coldata from thedata
      ) expanded_Data
JOIN col_list
  on col_list.col = expanded_data.col
where col_id = :your_id;
```

Set the id to 2 and get:

```
ROW_ID  COLDATA
1       12
2       22
3       32
4       42
```

So yes it can be done, but not truly dynamically as you need to be fully aware before-hand and hard-code the possible column name values that you are pulling from your table. If you need a truly dynamic select that may pick any column, or from any table, then you need to build your query dynamically and EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

**Edit - Add this caveat:**
I should add also that this only works if all of the possible columns grabbed are of the same datatype, or you will need to cast them all to a common data type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to store the value of numb, then reuse it in your SELECT statement, like this:

```
DECLARE @numb int
SET @numb = (SELECT cl1 from table2)

SELECT * from stat1 s WHERE s.numb = @numb
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to select the column name from table1, and inject it in his/her query